# Getting App Store receipt for sandbox user fails with incorrect password message

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sandbox, mac-app-store

I have a commercial macOS app I distribute in the Mac App Store. Now at startup I check for the App Store receipt and exit with code 173 if it is not present. This brings up the App Store sign in dialog in order to get a receipt.

I have always tested this with sandbox accounts but now I only get errors when I try to sign in with a sandbox account (or my real Apple ID).

[image: Apple ID Signin Error]

The issue emerges when I start from XCode as well as when I export the app as a development build.

I have the following setup:

- macOS 10.15.1
- XCode 11.2
- App signed with valid development certificate

I have tried the following:

- Sign out of App Store app
- Restart Mac
- Tripple verified email and password
- Create new sandbox user in App Store Connect
- Ran `codesign -vvvv` which reports everything is fine

I do, however, see the following error on the Console, but could not figure out what it is supposed to mean:

```
StoreLegacy: Failed to perform in-line receipt renewal for application 
at path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-alwjuasqcasdfaufnnxhqeoo/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app : 
'Error Domain=com.apple.commerce.client Code=600 "(null)"'
```

Has anybody seen this before?

---

**Update**

It works as expected on Mojave. So I assume this is an issue with Catalina.

Comment: Do u need to notarize?

Comment: @RichardBarber I don't think notarization is required for development builds. Also I just tested on Mojave and it works there...

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Same here for Catalina. I can also confirm that the same steps work under macOS High Sierra 10.13. Any news on this issues? Any workaround?

Comment: Finally! I was going crazy because I tried with a few sandbox accounts and nothing... I thought it was only me.

Comment: Same issue here with Catalina. Not tested on previous versions of macOS though. It works when I remove the exit(173) and its conditional test. But can I do that?? no idea

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you guys solve this issue please?

Comment: @Houman I have not yet solved the problem.

Comment: still no solution?

Comment: @Alan I tried it the other day on Big Sur with the XCode beta and it worked there. Let's see if it will still work in the final release or if there is some shortcut implemented in the beta...

Answer (score -1):

@codingFriend1 - Thanks. I should have posted the workaround. It seems the problem was that I'm in the UK and my test account was with the UK app store. I created a new tester with the US app store and that worked.

The resulting certificate works with UK tester. I don't think it used to be like this, but hey ho!

It was this that finally got it working for me but there may be other problems.