# Mac App Development: "***.app" is damaged and can't be opened

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, storekit, mac-app-store

I have a Mac App that I didn't touch for a while. Now, [it appears that something around running apps with Mac App Store integrations has changed since macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58673379/1879171).

When I launch the App from XCode it crashes with exit code 173 and logs as below, followed by a prompt to login with my Apple ID, which I tried both my lives as sandbox Apple ID.

[image]

Regardless of which Apple ID I am signing in with, it ends with an error:  *«"Appname" is damaged and can't be opened.»*

[image]

### Logs

```
Could not check for receipt presence for some reason... Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “receipt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt -- file:///Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*********-egqjyklohxjyjqcvtxjmwzdxvxhv/Build/Products/Debug/**********.app/, NSFilePath=/Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*********-egqjyklohxjyjqcvtxjmwzdxvxhv/Build/Products/Debug/**********.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c86310 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
2021-01-08 13:23:07.867823+0100 *********s[87637:4910885] Failed fetch receipt with error: The file “receipt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
Could not check for receipt presence for some reason... Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “receipt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt -- file:///Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*********-egqjyklohxjyjqcvtxjmwzdxvxhv/Build/Products/Debug/**********.app/, NSFilePath=/Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*********-egqjyklohxjyjqcvtxjmwzdxvxhv/Build/Products/Debug/**********.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c8dd40 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
2021-01-08 13:23:07.869011+0100 *********s[87637:4910885] Failed fetch receipt with error: The file “receipt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
Could not reach receipt URL: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “receipt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt -- file:///Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*********-egqjyklohxjyjqcvtxjmwzdxvxhv/Build/Products/Debug/**********.app/, NSFilePath=/Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*********-egqjyklohxjyjqcvtxjmwzdxvxhv/Build/Products/Debug/**********.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c8ddd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})
2021-01-08 13:23:07.882384+0100 *********s[87637:4910885] No receipt found! Will exit with 173 to let macOS handle renewing a receipt from the App Store.
```

### Setup

- macOS 10.15.7 (19H114)
- XCode 12.3 (12C33) // also tried it with XCode 11.7 → same same
- App signed with valid development certificate

Comment: Well turns out there is no answer to my issue given by the community. After a large amount of digging & debugging through my own 5+ years old code across the app project and a private Carthage framework of mine, I realized the logs were all produced by my own code. Event the 173 Exit is caused by my own implementation following Apple's  [Validating Receipts Locally Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2).

Comment: Lesson Learned: Make your homework and create documentation for also for your projects.  

FutureMe will be thankful for it.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the attributes via the `xattr` command. With that you can bypass e.g. your error message or others like when the [app cannot be opened as it wasn't installed from the AppStore](https://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/).

Anyhow, launch your terminal and use:

```
sudo xattr -cr {path_to_application}/application.app
```

With the [`xattr`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/xattr/) you're able to view the extended attributes themselves (and remove them) by applying

1. the `-c` flag with which you remove all attributes
2. and `-r` to act on all the files the directory tree is pointed to.

For both flags, as well as `xattr`, I'd suggest reading [this documentation](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/xattr/) page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I am sure your solution works with applications to use from arbitrary sources, unfortunately, it does not fit the development process when building my app in from XCode.